# How to correctly install bower component in angular (blueimp)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bower, bower-install

I´m just starting to work with Angularjs and have a simple issue with bower that don´t now how to solve it.

I was requested to implement "blueimp-gallery" in my project, I downloaded it from bower (bower install --s blueimp-gallery), this updated my **bower.json** and added "**blueimp-gallery": "~2.18.2"** to the dependencies.

In the index.html requested the CSS and JS that the gallery needs. Also implemented the needed js and html in the view and the controller.

It looks like when I run it and enter the view where I have implemented the gallery, doesn´t load the CSS and the JS that the gallery needs.

```js
view.controller.js

$(function () {
      'use strict'
      $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
        data: {
          format: 'json',
          method: 'flickr.interestingness.getList',
          api_key: '7617adae70159d09ba78cfec73c13be3'
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback'
      }).done(function (result) {
        var carouselLinks = []
        var linksContainer = $('#links')
        var baseUrl
        $.each(result.photos.photo, function (index, photo) {
          baseUrl = 'https://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' +
          photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret
          $('<a/>')
            .append($('<img>').prop('src', baseUrl + '_s.jpg'))
            .prop('href', baseUrl + '_b.jpg')
            .prop('title', photo.title)
            .attr('data-gallery', '')
            .attr('ng-click','handleClick($event)')
            .appendTo(linksContainer)
          carouselLinks.push({
            href: baseUrl + '_c.jpg',
            title: photo.title
          })
        })
      })
    })
```

```html
index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery-indicator.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery-video.css"> 
<script src="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-helper.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.js"></script>


view.html
<h2>Lightbox image gallery</h2>
<div id="links" class="links"></div>
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
<div class="slides"></div>
<h3 class="title"></h3>
<a class="prev">‹</a>
<a class="next">›</a>
<a class="close">×</a>
<a class="play-pause"></a>
<ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Perhaps I´m missing something but don´t know what.
Could you help me with this?

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console for errors. It should show you what's trying to load.

Comment: Actually the console show no errors, its just not loading the CSS and JS, specifically of blueimp, by the way I´m using gulp

Comment: If you're not seeing any 404 errors in the *Network* console, then it is loading the files correctly

Comment: I feel bad because the answer was very simple I just added an override on my **bower.json** file just like this and worked like charm, sorry for the question.

    "overrides": {
        "blueimp-gallery": {
          "main": [
            "css/blueimp-gallery.css",
            "css/blueimp-gallery-indicator.css",
            "css/blueimp-gallery-video.css",
            "js/blueimp-helper.js",
            "js/blueimp-gallery.js",
            "js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.js"
          ]
        }
      }